# reverse_merge returns hash instead of subclass. Is it a Bug or intended?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Summary: subclass.reverse_merge(class) returns class - not subclass

I have a small class extending `Hash`

```
class HtmlOptions < Hash
    def add_class 
    # add html-class like jQuery 
    …
    end

    (a little more)
end
```

So if I am using it like that with `merge`

```
input_options = HtmlOptions.new(…)
…
input_options.merge(id:"ovewrite_id").add_class("sample")
```

works as intended, while using `reverse_merge`

```
input_options = HtmlOptions.new(…)
input_options.reverse_merge(value:"default").add_class("sample")
#crashes
```

throws an error (add_class undefined).

Ok, passing `HtmlOptions` to both, does the trick like:

```
input_options.reverse_merge(HtmlOptions.new(value:"default")).add_class("sample")
```

So now I think this is a bug and correcting  it in my `HtmlOptions` class is ok. Because I can not think about a situation where this silent class change is intended.

On the other hand, if it ist the basic idea of reverse_merge to work like that strictly *reverse*, I should not change it in my class (and the bang-version of reverse_merge is wrong)

Can anyone tell me if this behavior i intended?, (and maybe tell me where to use it?)
Or just a bug.

Answer (score 1):

`reverse_merge` is just what it says: the reverse of merge. The [source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/66cabeda2c46c582d19738e1318be8d59584cc5b/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/reverse_merge.rb#L14-L16) for it is:

> ```rb
> def reverse_merge(other_hash)
>   other_hash.merge(self)
> end
> ```

That's why the result is the class of the object you pass in, rather than the object you're calling it with.

I think the best option would be to override `reverse_merge` for your `HtmlOptions` class; something like this:

```rb
def reverse_merge(other_hash)
  new(super)
end
```

Comment: The current provided versions of `reverse_merge` don't actually merges the the contents of `other_hash` into `self`. I would override `reverse_merge` with `merge(other_hash) { |_key, oldval, _newval| old_val }`